# Search for two values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$categories` and I would like to check if either 'computers' or 'laptops' are in the array. 
I can do

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'product_cat');

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $categories[] = $term->slug;
}

if (in_array( 'computers', $categories)) {
    //run a lot of code
}

if (in_array('laptops', $categories)) {
    //run a lot of code
}
```

but is there a way to combine with an OR so I don't have to write out the code twice?

something like

```
if ((in_array( 'computers', $categories)) OR (in_array('computers-he', $categories))) { 
    //run a lot of code
}
```

I tried it but it doesn't work I get.

> PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null

Comment: the "OR" operator in php is the operator "|" or "||"

Comment: you should do `$categories = array();` before the foreach to ensure it's an array (even an empty one).

Comment: An alternative to the obvious usage of the `||` operator is to put the "lot of code" into a separate function which you call depending on different conditionals. This often offers more flexibility. As a rule of thumb: you should create a separate function for a token of code that does a clearly defined and separated task. Encapsulate your code and call the function a name exactly describing what that code does.

Comment: LTech  check the answers below

Answer (score 4):

***1.*** Define

```
$categories = array();
```

before-

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'product_cat' );
```

***2.*** Use `||` like this:-

```
if(in_array('computers',$categories) || in_array('laptops',$categories)) {
  //run a lot of code
}
```

***Now full code will be:-***

```
$categories= array();
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'product_cat' );
foreach($terms as $term) {
   $categories[] = $term->slug;
}
if(in_array('computers',$categories) || in_array('laptops',$categories)) {
    //run a lot of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a different approach:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'product_cat');
foreach ($terms as $term)
{
    if(in_array($term->slug, ['computers', 'laptops']))
    {
        //run a lot of code
        break; //run the code once
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
if (array_intersect($categories, ['computers', 'laptops'])) { 
    //run a lot of code
}
```

If one or both terms are in `$categories`, it returns the array with those terms, if none are in it, it returns an empty array which is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

From you question, I guess you need to run code if there is at least one term of particular category. In such case you can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and take advantage of [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
$criteria = [
    'computers' => true,
    'laptops' => true
];

$test = function ($carry, $term) use ($criteria) {
    return $carry || isset($criteria[$term->slug]);    
};

if (array_reduce($terms, $test, false)) {
    echo 'Run a lot of code.';
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e9dd1e82f619ea037b9d97a7bd2b0222d25d434).